# how to handle save file dialog of firefox in selenium using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

i am using selenium for testing website which has functionality for  downloading online video.
i am using asp.net as language in selenium,each time i press download button save file dialog appears which cant be handle by selenium,
how can i handle save file dialog(without using autoIt exe file).
is there a way to call autoit script from selenium?
or any other method to handle save file dialog???
thanks

Comment: selenium is a tool to download online video??

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Selenium can not handle this because you can not do this with JavaScript as that would breach the JavaScript Sandbox.

Unfortunately I think that you would have to use AutoIT or have this as a manual test for your application.

Answer (score 1):

As AutomatedTester rightly said, it is not possible to handle firefox save file dialog since it is a windows based component. Selenium does not recognize any such components. Assuming that you are using Selenium RC, I suggest you to use 3rd party tools like AutoIt in this case. You dont need to write the whole test in AutoIt; simply invoke it(the exe file) at the point when you have to handle the save as dialog box. After it has completed its actions, the control will return back to selenium RC code. You can then continue with remaining steps after that. Please visit the [link](http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html) to learn more about using AutoIt along with selenium.
Hope this helps you,
Vamyip
=========================================================
Please remember to mark a reply as answer if it solves your query.